# What does "go about one's day" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/vN1aRN5bQQ0). It is at around 4 minute and 31 second. Here is the context:

> The chemistry of your brain is constantly changing as you **go about your day**.

Does that mean just during the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly. The meaning is closer to "live your everyday life". Let's look at it another way. Here's an entry for *go about* from TFD:

> [go about](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+about)
>   2. To execute some routine: From my office on the top floor, I could observe all the city's workers going about their business.

*Your day* just refers to your typical day, your daily activities. So another way to interpret "go about your day" is **execute your *daily* routine**.

Comment: +1 for "live your everyday life" but that dictionary's "execute" is an odd paraphrase for "go about"

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case with phrasal verbs made from the simplest of constituents like **go** and **about**, it is possible to derive the more abstract or figurative meaning from the basic literal meaning of the constituents.

If you "go about" you are moving here and there, moving from one place to another.

**Go about {a place}**  [literal]

> We can go about the country holding political rallies.
>
> We can go about a shop looking for bargains or objects that strike our fancy.
>
> We can go about a district assessing the damage from a natural disaster.

But you can also **go about {a task}** [figurative]

> go about your homework
>
> go about your assignment
>
> go about your business
>
> go about your chores
>
> go about your day

And there the meaning is "to *proceed* (to do)".

There, **your day** refers to all of the tasks you (one) regularly do in a day, where "tasks" is construed very broadly to mean "the purposeful things you do".